# Next.js Link position

Tags: next.js

```
<Link href={`/user/${username}`}>
  <List.Item active={router.query.username === username}>
    <List.Icon name="user" size="large" />
    <List.Content>
        <List.Header>
            <a>Account</a>
        </List.Header>
    </List.Content>
  </List.Item>
</Link>
```

If I use the next Link in the way above, my a tag is not a direct child of the next Link and my question is: is the href passed from Link to the a tag ? Otherwise I think It could hurt my web site SEO

(I now I can directly use Link around the a tag, I ask this because it could save my some styling)

Comment: From all of my usage and problems I've encountered, the `<a>` tag *should* be the next descendant of the `<Link>` It's usually always caused me a headache to try and work around it. Not sure if others will have an elegant solution for it. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Just wrap the group with a clickable link? If so - moving the a outside wont' hurt.

Comment: Yeah I only wanted to make the all clickable without using extra lines of css. Thanks for the suggestion. I thought wrapping more elements with an a tag wasn't as good

Comment: You're technically correct, but you can just as easily wrap everything in a single div and then wrap *that* div. ;)

Comment: Oh right. Thanks!